# Hibernate - my table is not mapped

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql

I want to make a simple query with a `getValueByLabel` Method:

Here is my code:

```
public Config getValueByLabel(String label) throws EntityPersistException{

    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("select id from config where config_label=:label",Long.class);
        query.setParameter("label", label);
        List<Long> config = query.getResultList();

        return em.getReference(Config.class, config.get(0));
    }
...
```

when I want to start the method I get:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: config is not mapped [select id from config where config_label=:label]
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

**UPDATE**

I am using:

hibernate 4.0.1.Final
and a postgresql db 1.16.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax of hql is case sensitive. please see if table/entity and column/instance variable names used in query are same as that of object.